# Set top level dependency version in npm v3

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm v3` uses flat structure of dependencies. So I have some modules that use different versions of the same dependence. Is it any way to set, which version of this dependence would be in the root of `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [npm shrinkrwap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to override nested dependency versions, forcing all dependencies to use the same version.

From the docs:

> This command locks down the versions of a package's dependencies so
>   that you can control exactly which versions of each dependency will be
>   used when your package is installed.

Unfortunately there has been a long running [issue with npm v3 and shrinkwrap](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9703). The ticket is still open, but the discussion does appear to include a branch that supposedly fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
But If some modules use the same dependence, which version of this dependence would be in the root? As I understood from documentation, In the root would be a version from the latest installed module?